# Android Emulator is running properly but cannot see application on it

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]I am a newbie to android development and have little experience of eclipse. My android emulator is working properly but I cannot see application running on it.

Any pointers would be great. Thanks in advance.

**MainACtivity.java**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.act`enter code here`ion_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: if your using eclipse, click the RUN button

Comment: can you show some UI that how it look like?

Comment: check adb connection once

Comment: Can you explain further? What did you do to show on your emulator? Did you select your project and click Run as ... Android Application, then select your emulator?

Comment: Emulators are sloooooow. Have you given it enough time to fully come up and launch your app? Took me about a semester's worth of time before I realized it is best to just keep the emulator up and running.

Answer (score 1):

use the 
 `AndroidManifest.xml`
 file, you can actually even have more than one launcher activity specified in your application manifest. To make an activity seen on the launcher you add these attributes to your activity in the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

set this inside your `<activity>` . hopefully it should work now. :)

Comment: my AndroidManifest.xml already has these enteries

Comment: @ShrutiJakhete so you have coded your application. when you run it. It doesn't launch your application.! Is that so.!?
Or Once you exit your running application from emulator, you are not able to view your application again? what scenario are you have issue!

Comment: I have coded a simple "hello world" application. When I  run it , it doesn't launch my application. Please see the image above, it just shows this screen.

Comment: @ShrutiJakhete: Okay. Can you please add your activity's java file and XML file along with Manifest file. It would be really helpful.

Comment: added the files above.. can you please comment